# Probability and measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[0,1] with Lebesgue measure can be considered as a probability space. 
Measure of irrational numbers (respectively transcendentals) in [0,1] is 1. Probability of an event being 1 is a sure event. So choosen any random number from [0,1], will it be irrational (respectively transcendental)?

Comment: It will, with probability $1$.

Comment: Well... almost surely.